# $1 < a$ and $b\ne0$ imply $1<a^b$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, order-theory, natural-numbers

> $1 < a$ and $b\ne0$ imply $1<a^b$ when $a,b$ are arbitrary nonnegative integers.

I've tried to prove it by induction.

[image: line number]
I've assumed that $b < a$ (Is valid my assumption?)

I'm using this definition for $a<b$
\begin{align*}
a<b \Leftrightarrow (\exists k\in \mathbb N)a + (k + 1) = b\\
\end{align*}

### Base P(1)

$0<1\le 1 < a \implies1<a^1$

$1<a^1 \equiv (1+(k+1))^1=a^1$

### Hyphotesis P(n)

$0<1\le n < a \implies1<a^n$

$1<a^n \equiv (1+(k+1))^n=a^n$

### Induction step

$0<1\le n + 1 < a \implies1<a^{n+1}$

we have     $(1+(k+1))^n*(1+(k+1))=a^n*a$ (hyphotesis)

then $(1+(k+1))^n = a^n$, because $(1+(k+1)) = a$ (base)

(here I used the property $ac= bc => a = b$ with $c \ne 0$)

Comment: @ZacharySelk b is positive since I am working with natural numbers and $b≠0$.

Comment: @Bernard I've missed this "a,b,c are arbitrary nonnegative integers".

Comment: "*I've assumed that $b<a$*"  This is an invalid assumption.  You will need to use double-induction here and prove it for *all* $a,b$ pairs, not just those where $b$ is smaller.  Have you proven yet the property that given $x\geq 1$ and $y\geq 0$ that $xy\geq y$?  Using this you have $a^{n+1}=a^n \cdot a \geq a^n > 1$ where the first inequality is from the mentioned property and the final inequality is from the induction hypothesis when inducting over the exponent.  And then inducting over $a$ is straightforward since if $a>1$ it should be clear that $a+1$ is also greater than $1$.

Comment: May be you could start with the opposite and prove its impossible. $ 1> a^{b}$ implies $log(1)> b.log(a)$. However, log a is not negative for $a >=1$...You can complete the proof. Note the case of $b <0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't valid to assume $b < a$ and you never used it

I can't follow your induction step.

If we assume $1 < a^n$ then $a^{n+1}=a^n*a$ and we want to prove $a^n*a > 1$ or that there is a $k\in \mathbb N$ so that $1 + (k+1)= a^n*a$

We know that $1 < a$ so there is a $j$ so that $1 +(j+1)=a$. And we know that $1 < a^n$ and that there is an $m$ so that $1+(m+1) =a^n$ so $a^{n+1} = (1 + (j+1))(1 + (m+1)) = 1 + (j+m+2) + (j+1)(m+1)$.  So let $k = (j+m+2) + (j+1)(m+1)\in \mathbb N$ and we are done.

Comment: I understand what you did here but there's a detail I don't know why is here: $1 + (k+1)= a^n*an$ why is that last n here? I expected it to be $1 + (k+1)= a^n*a$, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that induction is required for this proof. Proof by two cases:

Case 1: If $b=1$ then it is obvious that $a^b=a>1$.

Case 2: If $b>1$ then $a^b=a\cdot a^{b-1}\geq a>1$

The first inequality, that $a^{b-1}\geq 1$, is justified by the fact that any power of a nonzero natural number is itself a nonzero natural number (since $\mathbb{N}$ equipped with multiplication has no non-zero zero divisors).